# Is there a way so as to edit your title-bar for tkinter in pyton

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

For a default tkinter window we get a default title bar like where you get the title of the GUI window, is there a way to customize it using ttkthemes or any other module or codes?

Comment: Read through [`[Tkinter] Custom Title Bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+custom+title+bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only thing you can do is just to change the title of the window.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. You can set the text that appears, but that's the only customization provided by tkinter.